# Enhance this RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write content of .htaccess such a way that do the following conversion:

`www.abc.com/page.php?id=1` to `www.abc.com/page/1`

So I tried to use the following `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteRule    ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    page.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

I'm wondering, If page.php needs more that 1 PHP request, for instance, `id` and `pagenum` or even 3 or more, what is the best way to implement this (while using BeautifulURL)?

I tried to use `www.abc.com/page/1?pagenum=5` but it does NOT working, as you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a URL like: `www.abc.com/page/1?pagenum=5`, you need the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

or else the `pagenum=5` won't get added. Additionally, you can have the URL look (optionally) like this:

```
http://www.abc.com/page/1/5
```

for: `/page.php?id=1&pagenum=5` using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1&pagenum=$2 [L,NC]
```

You'd need both rules if you want both to work, with the extra `/5` at the end and without it.